# Min-Max Principle with matrices - Understanding $\lambda_2$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Related to the question [Min-Max Principle $\lambda_n = \inf_{X \in \Phi_n(V)} \{ \sup_{u \in X} \rho(u) \}$ - Explanations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827876/min-max-principle-lambda-n-inf-x-in-phi-nv-sup-u-in-x-rhou/1828953?noredirect=1#comment3740565_1828953), I am trying to do the same with $$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 7 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 7
\end{bmatrix}.$$ I'd like to understand the Min-Max Principle (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)) on $\lambda_2$, i.e. $$\lambda_2 = \min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^3} \{\max_x \{R_A(x) : x \in X, x \not = 0 \text{ and } \dim X = 2\}\}.$$ In the mickep's answer, it is rather simple to understand that if we work on $\lambda_1$, the subspaces $X$ are simply lines. So the Rayleigh quotient $R_A$ is constant in each $X$ because $$\rho(tu)=
\frac{\langle Atu,tu\rangle}{\langle tu,tu\rangle}=
\frac{\langle Au,u\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle}=
\langle Au,u\rangle \text{ with }\|u\|=1.$$ I would like to simplify my problem in such way, but I don't know if I can do it. Is there anyone could tell me if there exists an equivalent way to do it with the $2$-dimensional subspace $X \subset \mathbb{R}^3$?

A thing I know so far is there exists an orthonormal basis $\{w_1, w_2\}$ is each $2$-dimensional subspace $X$, but I just don't know if it could be useful for the problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**P.S.** If my question is unclear, please let me know. Furthermore, Jeb's answer is well, but I would like to get another answer if possible. I would have like that someone use the explicit formula to respond in my question. In fact, the important thing I want to understand is the notion of subspace that Jeb didn't use in his answer, i.e. something with image, geometric.

Comment: since you didn't say what you understood, we can't help you so much. did you prove the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices ? the SVD ? did you prove what I said in the other discussion, that for computing the SVD (the eigenvectors / eigenvalues if the matrix is symmetric matrix) all you need is computing iteratively the largest eigenvector $x_k = \arg\max_{\|x\|=1} \|A_k x\|$, starting with $A_1 = A$, and then $A_{k+1} = A_k + x_k \lambda_k x_k^T$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of writting Jeb's solution is the following.

Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of eigenvectors of $A$ associated to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\lambda_3$. Let  $V=\text{span}\{v_2,v_3\}$.

If $X$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $\dim(X\cap V)\geq 1$. Let $u\in X\cap V$ with norm 1. Thus $u=av_2+bv_3$, $a^2+b^2=1$.

Now, $R_A(u)=a^2\lambda_2+b^2\lambda_3\geq \lambda_2$, since $a^2+b^2=1$.

So $\max_x \{R_A(x) : x \in X, x
\not = 0 \text{ and } \dim X = 2\}\geq \lambda_2$, for every $X$. Hence, $\min_{X \subset \mathbb{R}^3}\{\max_x \{R_A(x) : x \in X, x
\not = 0 \text{ and } \dim X = 2\}\}\geq \lambda_2$.

Now, if we choose $X= \text{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$, we can prove in a similar way that $\max_x \{R_A(x) : x \in X, x
\not = 0 \text{ and } \dim X = 2\}= \lambda_2$.

Therefore, $\min_{X \subset \mathbb{R}^3}\{\max_x \{R_A(x) : x \in X, x
\not = 0 \text{ and } \dim X = 2\}\}\leq \lambda_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're jumping the gun with this question... I'd like to take a few steps back then work up to whats going on here. If $A$ is a hermitian matrix ( or symmetric for real matrices) then all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real (why?) and the eigenvectors are orthogonal (also why?). This allows us to rewrite our basis in terms of these eigenvectors.  i.e. if $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then 
$$ x = c_1 \vec { \lambda_1} + c_2 \vec{ \lambda_2} + c_3 \vec{\lambda_3}\quad c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$$
with $\vec{\lambda_i}$(the eigenvectors) normalized. Now it's easy to see our inner product with $A$ produces
$$ (x, A x ) = c_1^2  \lambda_1 + c_2^2 \lambda_2 + c_3^2 \lambda_3 $$
let's restrict ourself to $x$ being of unit length as well, i.e.
$$ ||x||^2 = c_1^2 + c_2^2+c_3^2 =1 $$
Now we see
$$ \frac{  (x, A x )}{||x||^2 } =  c_1^2  \lambda_1 + c_2^2 \lambda_2 + c_3^2 \lambda_3  $$
It's easy to see that the max is obtained at the largest eigenvalue since if $a<1$, we have $a^2 <a$. Thus
$$ \max_{||x||=1} \frac{  (x, A x )}{||x||^2 }  = \max_i \lambda_i $$
If we take out the linear subspace generated by $ A x - \max_i \lambda_i x=0$, i.e. $\vec \lambda_i$, we see the resulting subspace contains elements of the form above but missing the $\vec \lambda_i$ term. Now you repeat how we found $ \max_i \lambda_i$, to find the next largest eigenvalue.

Edit: Let's see how this pans out for the exact matrix you've given. One may easily check that the eigenvalues and vectors of your matrix are
$$ \lambda = 8,6,2 \quad \vec \lambda = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
You know that any element in $\mathbb{R}^3$ may be written  as
$$ x = c_1  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + c_2  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+ c_3  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
and we have that
$$ (x,Ax) = 8 c_1^2 + 6c_2^2 + 2 c_3^2 $$
Now if we restrict to the unit sphere, we see 
$$\max_{||x||=1} (x,Ax) = 8$$
if we restrict to the sphere and cut out the subspace generated by $(0,-1,1)$, we have
$$ \max_{||x|| =1 \setminus span \vec \lambda_1} (x,Ax) = 6 $$
and if we cut off $\vec \lambda_2$ as well, the vectors we're allowed look like 
$$x = c_3  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
Thus
$$ \max_{ ||x|| =1 \setminus span \vec \lambda_1,\vec \lambda_2} (x,Ax) = 2 $$
notice this works from the top down, you can reverse the procedure but taking the minimum on the sphere, but then remove vectors to move up as well.

Comment: Something like that... I'm trying to show you what these subspaces, and how you construct them in a simple manner.

Comment: 1. yes $ \vec \lambda$ is the eigenvector for $\lambda$ 2. When I wrote basis, I meant whatever basis the vector space we're working with was naturally is equipped with. 3. I made a typo, I should have wrote $||x||=1 $ instead of $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, I've edited it.  4. There is no loss of generality since the the min/max of $(x,Ax)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is $\pm \infty$ or $0$ depending on the eigenvalues. To make the question interesting we restrict to a sphere so the scaling of $||x||$ doesn't impact the answer.

Comment: Jeb assumes the spectral theorem that $P^T A P = D$ where $P$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal, i.e. that the $\vec{\lambda_i}$ are mutually orthogonal

Comment: I don't assume the spectral theorem... we have it for free since the matrix is hermitian.

Comment: your two first formulas : $x = \sum_i c_i \vec{\lambda_i}$ and $\langle x,Ax\rangle = \sum_i c_i^2 \lambda_i$ assume it